# How does the computer make the difference between types?

Tags: c, binary, cpu, computer-science

I am wondering how my computer can make the difference between the exact same set of 0s and 1s. I don't really know what should be the question but I want to know for instance when I have in C :

```
int main(){
   __uint8_t a = 97;
   printf(" Here is a char : %c\n Here is a number : %d\n", a, a);
   return 0;
}
```

How does it know when he rather should print 'a' or 97. I know it is due to the %c and %d, but what is going on really ?

Thank you all !

Comment: The implementation of the `printf` function decides how to interpret the format string and the arguments. If you want more details, you can look up the source code for the `printf` function.

Comment: so here is my question : how does printf know how to interpret the string ?

Comment: Somewhere there's probably some kind of translation table that translates the integer `97` to the character `a`. But it doesn't happen in the `printf` function, but rather when the value is printed to the terminal.

Comment: Like I said, have a look at the `printf` source if you want the actual details on how it does it.

Comment: I would like to go even further, in term of binaries code, of the cpu does know that it is a char or a number ? is there some metadata ?

Comment: The CPU only understands binary numbers. The interpretation and semantics are done through software implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering how my computer can make the difference between the exact same set of 0s and 1s.

In the general case, different instructions interpret the same sequence of bits differently.  For example, the x86 `ADDL` instruction interprets its operands as 32-bit integer values, while `ADDSD` interprets its operands as scalar double-precision floating point values.

The type information you specify in your source code (`int`, `double`, `char`, etc.) determines what machine instructions the compiler generates.  For example, if you have the code

```
double a = 1.0, b = 2.0;
double c = a + b;
```

the compiler will translate that to

```
movsd   -8(%rbp), %xmm0     // move value of a (1.0) to xmm0 register
addsd   -16(%rbp), %xmm0    // add value of b (2.0) to value in xmm0, store result in xmm0
movsd   %xmm0, -24(%rbp)    // copy value in xmm0 (3.0) to c
```

If you change `double` to `int`:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
int c = a + b;
```

then the compiler generates the code:

```
movl    -4(%rbp), %edx   // move value of a (1) to edx register
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax   // move value of b (2) to eax register
addl    %edx, %eax       // add value in edx to eax, store result in eax
movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)  // copy value in eax to c
```

For your specific question, though:

> I know it is due to the %c and %d, but what is going on really ?

The integer *value* `97` is stored as a sequence of bits - assuming an 8-bit type, that bit sequence is `01100001`, or `0x61`.

The `%c` basically says "present this value as the corresponding symbol in the basic character set" - IOW, the symbol `'a'`.  Somewhere there's a mapping between integer values and corresponding symbols.

The `%d` conversion specifier basically says "create a *decimal string representation* of this value" - that is, emit the *sequence* of characters `{'9', '7'}`.

Exactly how values are mapped to characters and displayed is a function of the implementation and the terminal driver, and that will vary from system to system.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is exactly what I was looking for ! I did a bit of assembly language in ARM so I’m a bit confused with those registers

Answer (score 1):

That `%c` or `%d` you mentioned are called conversion specifier, each one of them have *specific* meaning. They are pre-decided that how the corresponding argument will be treated, formatted and printed.

Quoting from `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, some examples:

> 8. The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> > `d,i` The int argument is converted to signed decimal in the style *[−]dddd.*
>
> and
>
> > `c` If no `l` length modifier is present, the `int` argument is converted to an
> > `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written.

Like that, each conversion specifier has associated rules on how they interpret and print the supplied arguments or ignore them (ex: `%%`).

Comment: Thank you sir, so where can I find where the argument will be treated, formatted and printed ? Because in the source code of printf, nothing of this appears

Comment: @EliasEl where or how? If it's "where" you ask: check the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) of printf for the details.

Comment: so now I will ask : how?

Comment: @EliasEl not sure what source you looked at, but certainly the source for `printf` will at some point get to the handling of the arguments and the formatting. Now `printf` may call another function to handle some of the detailed work, so you'd need to chase down the source for any functions that `printf` may call. But it's all there.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask to print with %c the computer will look toward the ASCII table. Computer can only understand numbers (binary) and this table is a reference of how to change a number to a character (see below) as you can see a = 97 in decimal equal 0110 0001 in binary. In code, you can ask to display a value in different formats (%d for decimal, %f for float, %c for char ...) but it is always a binary word in the computer

[image: ASCII table]

Ask me if you want more information about low hardware layers

Answer (score -1):

Computer does not know. You tell him by `%c` and `%d`in the `printf` format string.

And it is an conension used bt this particular architecture to use ASCII codes, where 97 is `a`

You can write your own output function  using any coding you like.